# Rails Plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is it possible to include view code in a plugin, such that an app using the plugin can simply call reference the view code like it might reference one of its own partials.

Am I off track here or are there good examples of plugins which do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the engine stuff that's already built into Rails 2.3, I've done it with [calenduh](http://github.com/radar/calenduh). This is supposedly vastly improved in the up and coming Rails 3.

Comment: Does that mean rails engines will be built-in with Rails3?

Comment: Thanks Radar, so rails engines looks like the way to go.. its relatively new so are there any gotchas to look out for.. Can I package all the static assets (css, images etc) with the rails engine?

Comment: @jpartogi: yup

@Dom: You can't package them but if you look at calenduh I've added something to install.rb that will copy them over to public.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You can do that with [Rails Engines](http://rails-engines.org/).</del>

This functionality has long-since been moved into Rails. [Here's a guide](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/) for getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Kaminari does this.  It has default views for pagination which you can override by generating views and editing them and the gem searches for them. Is that what you mean?